# Nginx on Windows with ASP.NET and the Microsoft .NET framework?

Tags: windows, nginx, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Question:

Is it possible to use nginx **on Windows** to serve ASP.NET / ASP.NET MVC pages **using the Microsoft .NET framework** ? 
I know one can do it with mono-fastcgi, but I was wondering if it is possible with the Microsoft Framework alone, that is to say, without mono or any of its components.

Answer (score 2):

No of course not, Microsoft have no reason to provide ASP.Net for Nginx.

If you are using Windows, then use IIS (or if you must Apache).  On Windows, Nginx is very ropey, [to quote the manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html):

> Version of nginx for Windows uses the native Win32 API (not the Cygwin
>   emulation layer). Only the select() connection processing method is
>   currently used, so high performance and scalability should not be
>   expected. Due to this and some other known issues version of nginx for
>   Windows is considered to be a beta version.

Windows running Nginx/FastCGI/Mono, aside from an academic exercise to see if it's possible,  is a terrible idea.  If you philosophically don't want to use the Microsoft stack then do it properly and run Nginx/FastCGI/Mono on Linux - [it's pretty simple to setup.](http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI_Nginx)

Answer (score 0):

Welll.... nginx is little used on Win...  To host your asp.net/mvc app, you really should do that in iis for best results.

To use nginx in addition to iis... you could put it all on one box. (Though if traffic is high, perhaps that is not a good idea.)